# Boundary Value Problem $y^{(4)} =-24$ a horizontal beam in theory of elasticity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is $$y^{(4)} =-24$$
boundary values are $y(0) = y'(0) = y(4) = y'(4) = 0$. I integrated the equation four times and got $$y = -x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$$ but if I used character equation $r^4 + 24 = 0$ I will get complex roots, the soln will be cos and sin?! The problem has a part 2, it wants me to prove maximum displacement occurs at the center of the beam $x=2$. I solved for a,b,c,d and use second derivative test, but only found y(2) is a minimum?! Anyone got an idea on this weird question? I am confused why the problem is named "boundary value problem" as well, didn't we assign initial value to the equation and solve it?

Comment: Maybe this character will help: ‽.

Comment: @EricTressler LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic equation you quote does not apply to your equation, because the exponential $e^{r x}$ from which such an equation derives does not cancel.  (Thik about the equations in which you make such an assumption about the solution.)  The correct way is to integrate 4 times, as you did.  The boundary values get applied as follows:

$$y(0)=0 \implies d=0$$

$$y(4) = 0 \implies 64 a+ 16 b+ 4 c + d = 256$$

etc.

Comment: Thanks duder I see the problem now, solving $r^4 e^{rt} = -24$ is impossible it is not like right hand side zero.